# If statement: String starts with exactly 4 digitis in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a column of a dataframe consisting of strings, which are either a date (e.g. "12-10-2020") or a string starting with 4 digits (e.g. "4030 - random name"). I would like to write an if statement to capture the strings which are starting with 4 digits, which is similar to this code:

```
string[0].isdigit()
```

but instead of isdigit, it should be something like:

```
is string which starts with 4 digits
```

I hope I clarified my question and let me know if it is not clear. I am btw working in pandas.

Comment: While I generally don't recommend regular expressions, this might an instance where it could be simple and useful. I suggest you do some research about *regular expressions* and how to use them in Python.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's interesting you feel that way, perhaps because you are a C/C++ guru.  In Python and the field of data science, regex is very much ubiquitous.

Comment: Any reason why `string[:4].isdigit()` will not do what you want? You will get false matches if the data is not all as you describe.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The following code has solved my problem:
if i[:4].isdigit():

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains`:
col"

```py
df[df["col"].str.contains(r'^[0-9]{4}')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) that is anchored by default to the start of the string:

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['4030 - random name', 'other', '07-02-2022']})

df[df['col'].str.match('\d{4}')]
```

output:

```
                  col
0  4030 - random name
```